# Library to extract data from html string

Tags: c#, .net, html, html-parsing

Is there any free/open source c# libraries to extract data from html?

Given the input below

```
<div style="...">
 text part 1
</div>
<div style="...">
 text part 2
</div>
```

I want the output to be:

```
text part 1 text part 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [HtmlAgilitiPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) very good library.

and then:

```
public string StripHTMLTags(string str)
        {
            StringBuilder pureText = new StringBuilder();
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(str);

            foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                pureText.Append(node.InnerText);
            }

            return pureText.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse HTML using Xpath queries as if it were XML.